# Security.Principal.IIdentity extension method for getting user email

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

Inside my project ASP I'm using ASP.NET Identity 2.2.1. In many places I must get current (logged-in) user email.
Right now I'm finding that user using this:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId<int>());
var email = user.Email;
```

I've noticed that `GetUserId<T>` is an extension method that can be found inside `IdentityExtensions` class inside `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`

I've created my own extension method that simplifies getting email by allowing to get it as:

```
var email = User.Identity.GetUserEmail()
```

Below is my extension:

```
public static class MyIIdentityExtensions
{
    public static string GetUserEmail(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        if (identity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("identity");
        }
        var ci = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        if (ci == null) return null;
        var um = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserManager>();
        if (um == null) return null;
        var user = um.FindById(ci.GetUserId<int>());
        if (user == null) return null;
        return user.Email;
    }
}
```

But it is much more complicated than [build-in extension methods](https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/2.2.1-rtm-150310/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Extensions/IdentityExtensions.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core)

Can I simplify this? Maybe there is build in method for doing this? What I want is simple way to get `Email` for current logged in user from User.Identity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `UserManager`, you hit the database each time you call `GetUserEmail` method.

Instead you can add the email as Claim. Inside  `ApplicationUser` class there is  `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` method

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
{
     // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
     var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
     // Add custom user claims here
     userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, this.Email));
     return userIdentity;
}
```

Then your extension method to get it

```
public static class IdentityExtensions
{
    public static string GetUserEmail(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        if (identity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("identity");
        }
        var ci = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        if (ci != null)
        {
            return ci.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I totally forgot about `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` method. I even have same comment `//Add custom user claims here`. I have one more 'extra' question: Can I remove that claim from JWT token that is returned when user logs. What I want is to return minimal set of data inside JWT token. But from other side if I remove that Claim from token in all request I won't be able to get that email address, because I won't have that claim.

Comment: @Misiu that line of comments is there from default mvc5 template :)
About your extra question, its not clear what you want to. You want to add the claim on some requests?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I'd like to have that claim accessible on server side but not send to client inside JWT token. Probably this isn't possible, but I'd like to be sure.

Comment: Thank You for help! BTW did You noticed my previous comment? Is this even possible?

Comment: @Misiu I did. I do not think it is possible. The claim is stored in JWT, we are not quering the database its request.